# Projection of PCA into new variable space (study area)

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have a set of >30 variables distributed in x,y coordinates across two study areas. I'd like to reduce that dimensionality with a PCA applied in the first study area. Then I'd like to visualize how those main components change distribution in the second study area.

This means "fitting" the PCA to the first area and "projecting" it to the second one, just based on the eigenvalues and variable loadings/contributions of the first one.

Is this incorrect? I've never seen anyone doing it and I'm struggling to apply it.

In practice i imagine something like this:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np

# Perform PCA fit and transform on control data
pca = PCA(n_components = 3)

# Different representations of same variables
X1 = np.array([[2,2,3,..., 5,74],   # Each row is a variable
                   ....            # Each column is a point regularly distributed in the variable space (colapsed to 1D)
              [2,2,3,..., 5,74]])
X2 = np.array([[12,2,3,..., 51,12,5,91,5], # Exactly same number of variables (rows) 
                   ....       # But different number of columns (as the study area/variable space is bigger)
              [52,82,30,..., 5,56,91,3,3]])

# Fit PCA to control slide (0) and project it onto condition slide (X2)
pca_model = pca.fit(X1)
predict = pca_model.transform(X2)
```

Kind regards,

Comment: Yes, this seems to be right solution. Are you facing any issues with the output of this?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the interest. It works if I transpose my X1 and X2 objects, so that the columns are variables, not the rows.  
I've just never seen this kind of projection being done anywhere, hence my doubts.